# Setting JSON key with indexed array value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a JSON object by automatically setting the keys for an JSON object based on the string value of another array. For example,

```
var test = ["a","b"]
{test[0]:"A"}
```

[image]

However, I get a Syntax error when I do this, if I manually set the value as the string as shown in the third line `{"a":"A"}` this issue does not happen. I've checked that `test[0]` does indeed print out `"a"` and its datatype is a string. Is there any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried `{test:["A"]}`?

Comment: `{[test[0]]:"A"}` results in `{a: "a"}` - surround your key in brackets, else its trying to write the key as `test[0]`

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) ... what you have is an object literal. That has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: you are looking for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: *"Is there any reason why this might be happening?"* Yes, `x[y]` is simply not valid syntax in place of the key in an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
    var test = ["a","b"]
    var obj = {
        [test[0]]:"A"
    };
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, could you explain why the brackets around test[0] is necessary in this case?

Comment: It is used for computed property names . For reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names